# Error pushing a large commit (containing PySide6 package) to GitHub

Tags: python, github, qt-designer, pyside6

I have a PySide6 project that I am currently working on it, when I tried to add a source control to the project, I realized that the PySide6 package is too large (+450 MB) to be pushed to GitHub.
The error:

```
File .venv/Lib/site-packages/PySide6/Qt6WebEngineCore.dll is 127.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Beside pushing to the GitHub issue, the project itself is huge in size.
Is there any solution to this problem?
Can I install PySide6 without included Qt designer?

I tried searching the web for a solution, but actually there is not much about PySide6 in general on the web.

Comment: I would definitely recommend _not_ having a virtual environment in your GitHub repository. Add it to the .gitignore file, and create a requirements.txt instead with all the versions of packages you are using. That way anytime you need to clone your repository, you build a new virtual environment and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get the required packages.

Comment: yeah now I understand, I should not include the virtual environment in the first place. thanks a lot.

Comment: Moreover, uploading virtual environments is completely useless: a lot of variables within the environment are hardcoded to be paths specific to your machine (e.g. navigating to your users or home directory), which would be invalid paths on any other machines without your specific configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git should only be used to track the source files of your project. The compiled outputs and installed virtual environments should be excluded from source control. Basically, everything that can be regenerated locally should be excluded.

Otherwise the git will be cluttered with unnecessary and not up-to-date files like:

- Compiled files
- Virtual environments
- Temporary files
- ...

Extending for python:

Specifically for python, there is the possibility of using the `requirement.txt` file. All required packages are listed there with the required version and can then be installed with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.